# Change css on button when clicked in a loop

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<td *ngFor="let item of payment ;  let y=index">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="example">
        <button type="button" (click)="toggle(y)" class="btn-primary">Card</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="toggle(y)" class="btn-primary cash" [ngClass]="item.type === "cash" ? 'cash' : 'card'" >Cash</button>
        <button type="button" (click)="toggle(y)" class="btn-primary credit" [ngClass]="item.type === "credit" ? 'credit' : 'card'" >Credit</button>
    </div>
</td>
<-- below is for checkboxes not important... -->
<td *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxlist >
    <td *ngFor="let data of product">
     ....
```

I have a table looked like below and above is the snippet of what I need to change but stucked on.

```
               (tom)                         |               (sam)                    
 Type     Card        Cash         Credit    |    Card        Cash         Credit                    
  1    [CheckBox[x] | CheckBox[]| CheckBox[] |  [CheckBox[] | CheckBox[] | CheckBox[x]
  2    [CheckBox[x] | CheckBox[]| CheckBox[] |  [CheckBox[] | CheckBox[] | CheckBox[x]
  3    [CheckBox[x] | CheckBox[]| CheckBox[] |  [CheckBox[] | CheckBox[] | CheckBox[x]
...
```

what I am trying to do is change the css for the type of one column when I clicked on the specific type row (ex. Card, Cash, Credit). The button on one of those three would change. But my implementation currently would change the css for all the Card even on the 2nd column. So if I pressed Cash then both (tom) and (sam) Card would change the color. I want just (tom) to change if I press change on the (tom). What should I do to limit just one column being changed?

Comment: Is tom/sam separate component implementations? Do you have view encapsulation turned off or something? They should be applying an additional specificity selector like [ng-content*] to the elements so each component's styles apply just to the component via specificity like tom would become `[ngcontent-123] .card` for its css and not allow the class to bleed out to others. Perhaps not understanding the correction correctly though. Also should remove the base classes from the static `class=` declarations.

Comment: no it is the same component implementation. I dont use view just straight table setup. There is no ng-content because I am not adding anything onto it. I do agree that class = declaration needs to removed I have done so.